# Show changes after mysql update to database

Tags: jquery, ajax, live

For my personal project, I'm trying to make a point system. Basicly what I want to do is: Click a button (Jquery) and then send a query to the database, and finally show the user the points that are automaticly updated. I figured I could use ajax.

```
$(this).html('Thank you for granting EXP!');
var dataString = 'username=' + username+ '&name='+ name + '&count=' + count + '&message_id=' + message_id;

    $.ajax({
    type: "POST",
    url: "index.php?&page=profile",
    data: dataString,
    success: function() {
        $('#skills').load('./modules/skill_table.php');
    }
    });
```

This Ajax request requests the right page. On that page there is a MySQLi Query, which also executes fine. The problem is that I want to reload the correct div displaying the points AFTER I done the query. When it reloads the div I don't see any changes. Any suggestions on what I could do? I'm new to ajax calls like this. I could do something with the (data) response but does that mean I have to writhe a seperate php file for just this request?

EDIT: The code above works. It executes the MySQL Query and updates the database. the .load(); function ALSO WORKS! when I try .load('someotherfile.php'); It display the other file. The problem is: when I try to reload the current module (skill_table.php) It displays the old values and not the updates ones. I hope this explanation is a little bit better.

It reload the skill_table.php module with the new database values, but it shows the old ones.

Comment: AJAX is short for "Asynchronous JavaScript and XML", with emphasis on asynchronous. So you shouldn't use methods like waiting a specific amount of time but rather use the hooks jQuery provides with that function. See: http://api.jquery.com/jQuery.ajax/

Comment: Are you sure your update function is updating the database? How is the `$(this).html('Thank you for granting EXP!');` function called? Is it called before the update (like on page load?)

Comment: the thank you message is just a cosmetic change on the page. The actual query is made in index.php where it first checks if $_POST[] parameters are set and yes I'm sure it does update the database because the changes DO show on page refresh.

Answer (score 1):

Here's a more complete example on how to make an effective POST request and capture the response in the AJAX and return it in one shot. This is just one of many ways to do it, and please know the example is vague. Please learn from it and mould it to your needs.

**Your AJAX Request**

```
$.post(
    // This is the URL your posting to
    'index.php?page=profile', 
    // This is the JSONified version of your post data
    {
        "username":username,
        "name":name,
        "count":count,
        "message_id":message_id
    }, 
    // Handling your response here
    function(returnString) {
        // Check to ensure your php code worked
        if(returnString.success === 1) {
            // Insert your new DOM
            $('#skills').html(returnString.response);
        } else {
            // Send error message here
            window.alert('Oh noes! The world is ending!');
            // alertnatively
            //window.alert('Error:' + returnString.response);
        }
    }
);
```

**Hypothetical PHP File**

```
header("Content-type: application/json");

$mysqli->doMyAwesomeMySQLQueryHere();
$success = ($DidMyQueryWork) ? true : false;

echo json_encode(
        array(
            'success' => $success, 
            'response' => 'Your DOM Here'
        )
);
```

Comment: I have tried that, but it still doesn't work. After that I tried the setTimeout (as you can see above) but that doesn't work either :(.. what am I doing wrong?..

Comment: @RoanZuman "still doesn't work" is not an error description. Nobody would what does not work until you describe it.

Comment: The .load() JQuery function loads the correct module, but with not-up-to-date values from the database.

Comment: Odd... You might not be _actually_ updating the database then. You could do it differently and return the response on the index.php page and handle it through the returnString, manually placing it into the html with `$('#skills').html(returnString);` (as an example). @feela is correct, however, we need more information to help you better.

Comment: When I refresh the page as whole - It does show the changes to the database - so it must work right?.. And I don't have any experience with .html or returnString. I'm open to a whole new approach though. All I want is to use javascript to update a a database and reload the content to show the changes (or not reload the module and use Ajax response, but I should find out how that use that too).

Comment: @RoanZuman Check out my edits, I've taken the time to provide you a more in-depth answer and a look on the proper way to handle multifunctional ajax requests. Ideally you want to build your data set in the same request that makes your sql query and return the DOM.

Answer (score 1):

.load is pulling from the Cache. If this were a GET request, you could just tell it not to use the cache, but since you're POSTing, you'd have to add some arbitrary random element to the end of the loaded URL. Try this:

```
 $.ajax({
    type: "POST",
    url: "index.php?&page=profile",
    data: dataString,
    success: function() {
        $('#skills').load('./modules/skill_table.php?_=' + (new Date()).getTime();
    }
    });
```

Also, since you're using jQuery, check out .serialize() to help construct your dataStrings from an array.

http://api.jquery.com/serialize/

Answer (score 0):

You need to construct your data parameter correctly. IE, let jQuery construct it:

```
$(this).html('Thank you for granting EXP!');    
    $.ajax({
    type: "POST",
    url: "index.php?&page=profile",
    data: {'username' : username, 'name' : name, 'count' : count, 'message_id' = message_id },
    success: function() {
        $('#skills').load('./modules/skill_table.php');
    }
});
```

Answer (score 0):

it is better if you send your table or html inside ajax response (just one request will be send):

```
$.ajax({
  type: "POST",
  url: "index.php?page=profile",
  data: dataString,
  async:false,
  success: function(data) {
      $('#skills').html(data);
  }
});
```

**index.php:**

```
include('./modules/skill_table.php');
```